# How to move a bone in weight paint mode

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

How do I move a bone while in weight paint mode like the picture shows?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your file? so we can better understand what is your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select your armature, go to pose mode, then select the mesh and enter weight paint mode.
At this point you can select bones (with right click) and pose them without leaving weight paint mode.